# React & ASP.NET MVC 5 server side rendering console.log('text') does not show up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I have some code

index.cshtml

```
<div>
    @Html.React("App", new {i = 10})
</div>
```

App.jsx

```
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
       super(props);
       console.log(this.props.i);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>this.props.i</div>
        )
    }
}
```

The console.log in the constructor doesn't print out in my terminal for some reason, but it shows the value 10 properly in the html. Any suggestions for fixing this or debugging React in asp.net? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you rendering on the server? In that case, it would show up in the STDOUT of the server rather than in the browser dev console

Comment: Yea I might be now that you mention it

Comment: how do I see the STDOUT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
       super(props);
       console.log(this.props.i);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div> { this.props.i } </div>
        )
    }
}
```

> **You should see the console on Server console**
>
> ***NOTE*** the typo on your render method. (missing **{}**)